# Error while setting the Text in custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm working on the UI screen.

[image]

I'm making this screen 1st one from left. And I'm stuck at one point. i have made this much .[image].

I need to align the text in one direction and also how can i put this background image and when i'm putting buttons these are not visible on screen.

This is where i have set the view:

```
 <View style={styles.userInformations}>
 <View style={{ height: 195, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#22C1B9", }}>
 <Text style={styles.headline}>Dance</Text>
 <View style={styles.headlines}>
 <Text >3754 TRACKS</Text>
 </View>
```

And here i have Given the style:

```
headline: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 35,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
marginTop:80,
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    marginLeft:80,
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center',
},
headlines: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 20,
  marginTop: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 30,
  marginLeft:80,
  justifyContent: 'center', 
  alignItems: 'center',
},
searchBtnStyle: {
  marginTop: 15,
  backgroundColor: '#FFD701',
  borderColor: 'transparent',
  borderWidth: 0,
  borderRadius: 25,
  width: '80%',
  padding: 5
},
```

Comment: Please add your code as formatted text into the question. try to isolate it to the very problem. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: you may need to be more specific, it's hard to tell what you mean about aligning the text

Comment: Plzz check i have updated the question